# Reading an image into an array?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, sobel

I'm attempting to write a program that utilizes the sobel filter to detect edges in images. So first off, I've written down some of the requirements in some basic code, such as the x and y direction filters as arrays and also an attempt to read in a pgm image:

```
program edges
implicit none
integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: inp, outim, GX, GY
integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,300)
integer :: ky, kx, x, y, out_unit = 10, M, N, sx, sy, i, j
real(kind=dp) :: G
M = 5
N = 5

allocate(inp(M,N))
allocate(outim(M-2,N-2))
allocate(GX(3,3))
allocate(GY(3,3))

open(file = 'clown.pgm',unit=out_unit,status= 'unknown') !opening file to         write to inp
read (out_unit,11) 'P2'      !pgm magic number
read (out_unit,12) 50,50     !width, height
read (out_unit,13) 1      !max gray value
do M=-25,25
    do N=-25,25
        read (out_unit,*) inp(M,N)
    end do
end do
11 format(a2)
12 format(i3,1x,i3)
13 format(i5)
```

This is my first time working with image manipulation in FORTRAN, apart from once when I printed an image out as a pbm file. The code for reading the image in is a replicate of what I used to print one out before, except I changed write to read.

So my question is, how can I read in an image that's in pgm format into the "inp" array, so that I can apply the sobel filter? When I run my attempt, I get the following errors:

```
read (out_unit,11) 'P2'      !pgm magic number
              1
Error: Expected variable in READ statement at (1)
sobel.f90:41:18:

 read (out_unit,12) 50,50     !width, height
              1
Error: Expected variable in READ statement at (1)
sobel.f90:42:18:

 read (out_unit,13) 1      !max gray value
              1
Error: Expected variable in READ statement at (1)
```

Thank you

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thank you, i've reduced it down now and added the errors i'm getting.

Comment: Well, one can't read into literal constants.  Are you simply trying to validate - check the first line is "P2", etc.?

Comment: you allocate an array 5x5, evidently think the image is 50x50, then try to read 51x51 values into the array with indices starting at -25. ?

Answer (score 1):

The first mistake is, as the compiler states quite clearly, in this line:

```
read (out_unit,11) 'P2'
```

The compiler expects, because that's the way that Fortran is defined, to be told to read a value from `out_unit` into a variable, but `'P2'` is a character literal (or whatever the heck the standard calls them), it's a string, it's not a variable.

The same mistake occurs in the next lines too.  The compiler expects something like

```
integer :: p2  ! pgm magic number
...
read (out_unit,11) p2
```

*etc*.  After execution of this version of the read statement the variable `p2` holds the magic number read from the `pgm` file.

While I'm writing, calling the unit to be read from `out_unit` is just perverse and will, eventually, confuse you.

Comment: Thank you. So to fix the 'P2' issue, do I just declare it as a variable at the start of the code?

Comment: My mistake, I only did it for the input pgm and not the output, hence why I received the same error. How would this be applied to the other 2, i.e. the width/height and the max grey value? Do I declare them as variables above, evaluate them and then use them? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so I've fixed that. The error I get now : is "At line 43 of sobel.f90 (unit=10, file = "clown.pgm") 
Fortran runtime error: End of file"